# Websphere posts phantom (already handled) exception to log

Tags: jakarta-ee, exception, websphere, websphere-8

In our environment, we get a high volume of messages from a queue and handle them asynchronously.  For each message we need to create or lookup a row in the database.  We're following a typical create-get pattern to handle issues where two threads are addressing the same "parent" object:

```
public void ensure(Data d) {
  try {
    o = dao.create(d);
    log("Created");
  }
  catch(Exception x) {
    o = dao.get(d);
    if(o != null) {
      log("Existed");
    }
    else {
      event("Couldn't create or get parent!");
    }
  }
}
```

This works 100% of the time.  I always see the expected objects in the database and never see the "Couldn't create" message.  Excellent.

The ugly part about this is that even though the exception thrown from the create when the object already exists is caught and handled, I still see the exception in the logs, which understandably creates some confusion:

```
[7/16/15 11:11:37:930 EDT] 0000003b RegisteredSyn E   WTRN0074E: Exception caught from before_completion synchronization operation: <openjpa-2.1.2-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1636464 fatal store error> 

org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityExistsException: The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.
<Exception stacktrace omitted>
[7/16/15 11:11:37:942 EDT] 0000003b SystemOut     O Existed
```

Sorry, I can't post the entire stacktrace due to security issues.

Any idea how I can get this phantom exception to stop showing up in the logs?

**Edit to add more code:**

DAO:

```
public Data create(Data d) {
  UserTransaction utx = context.getUserTransaction();

      try {
        utx.begin();
        em.persist(d);
        utx.commit();
      }
      catch(Exception x) {
        throw MyException(x);
        // also tried simply returning null
      }
      // also tried catching Throwable
      return d;
    }
```

Comment: Doing this via exceptions seems like bad design to me. Why don't you search for the entry and if you don't get a result perform create. Or if you want to perform an update any way simply call merge on he entity manager instead?

Comment: Is this being driven from a message driven bean? Is the dao service an EJB?

Comment: @dngfng We used to have that design, but it doesn't work well in a multithreaded environment.  T1 and T2 both do a get and find that the object doesn't exist.  They both try to create and T1 succeeds, T2 then fails, then T2 needs to do a get again.  I'm not a fan of using exceptions as logic branches, but that's how the language is designed.

Comment: @SteveC Exactly!  This is a message driven bean calling a Stateless EJB DAO.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `ensure` was called in a transactional context (perhaps because it's an EJB), you will get this log message whenever an exception is thrown from `dao.create`.

The failure in [EntityManager.persist(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist-java.lang.Object-) causes the current transaction to be marked for rollback.

Therefore even though you caught the exception, WebSphere is warning you that your transaction was not committed. If you had made any changes to `o` they will not have been persisted.

This behaviour is by design and all app servers will do something like this because the JavaEE specs mandate it. Basically, any `java.lang.RuntimeException` that escapes an EJB method call will automatically mark the current transaction for rollback.

If you don't want this to happen then you should catch it in the DAO and throw a checked exception instead.

**Edit after further reading**

According to the JPA specification, the transaction is marked for rollback by the persist operation. Therefore, you need to arrange for the `create` method to run in it's own transaction. Typically this is done by:

```
@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)
public Data create(Data d) throw MyException {
    try {
       em.persist(d);
    } catch (PersistenceException e) {
       throw new MyException(x);
    }
    return d;
}
```

You still need the checked exception for the reasons outlined above.

By the way, we typically don't use the UserTransaction object because by default we get Container Managed Transactions (CMT).

Comment: That seems kind of obnoxious of WebSphere to ignore the whole concept of exceptions.  If I got an exception, of course nothing has been committed.  I just don't want the trash in the logs from an exception that has been handled.  If I understand what you're saying, it sounds almost as if I were able to wrap the call to dao.create in a non-transactional layer, it would avoid the message?

Comment: Updated response to answer your question

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to affect it at all.  I've tried catching Exception and rethrowing as a checked exception, tried catching Throwable and rethrowing as a checked exception, tried both and just returning null.  I added the DAO method to the post.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that you had updated your post.  I know CMT is the default, but we've had tons of trouble with it so we were given BMT a try.  I have the REQUIRES_NEW on the method, and the internal try/catch.  I notice that whatever is in that catch never gets executed though.  The catch in the ensure method DOES get executed though.  The message seems to be coming from some one-off thread that JEE is creating for the flush operation ("Exception caught from before_completion synchronization operation").